# Get C# out string paramater value to C++ BSTR*?

Tags: c++, casting, unmanaged, managed, firebreath

I have a method in C# DLL having one input and two output parameters. All the three are String.

I want to call that function from firebreath C++. How do I have to pass the BSTR* value from C++?. And how do I get that out values from C#?

I have already tried to get using

```
BSTR* userKey =NULL;
*userKey = ::SysAllocString(L"Hello Managed World");
```

But its not working.

C# function:

```
public void GetPublicKeyforEncryption(String ToUserEmailAddress, out String userKey , out String mySharedKey)
```

C++ Calling function:

```
std::wstring& ToUserEmailaddress;
BYTE **bEncryptData = NULL;
BSTR bsData = SysAllocStringLen(ToUserEmailaddress.data(), ToUserEmailaddress.size());
BSTR* userKey =NULL;
BSTR* mySharedKey =NULL;
CSharpInterface->GetPublicKeyforEncryption(bsData,userKey ,mySharedKey );
```

In the above c++ GetPublicKeyforEncryption bsData value is passed correctly,How will i allocate memory and Pass

```
   userKey ,mySharedKey in the BSTR* type
```

Anyone can solve this issue?
Help me.

Thanks
Sanju

Answer (score 2):

That's not correct code, BSTR is already a pointer type.  You need to pass a pointer to your BSTR variable so the called method can assign it.  Generic code that assumes just one `out string` argument:

```
BSTR retval = NULL;
HRESULT hr = CSharpInterface->SomeMethod(&retval);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
    // Use retval
    //...
    SysFreeString(retval);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Hans Passant.i already tried this.it gives,error C2664: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::basic_string(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'OLECHAR' to 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &'

Comment: My code snippet doesn't use std::string so cannot generate that compile error.  Converting from BSTR to std::wstring requires a cast to wchar_t* to tell the compiler that you are aware that this can cause data loss.